# In grave doubt about my newly offered job

Tags: riba

I am working as a research analyst in a capital market service firm in India. My current job is to study various companies in the capital goods industry (i.e. companies which manufacture construction equipments, mining equipments, power generation equipments, etc.) and recommend the client whether to invest or not to invest on a particular company in the above industry. Very recently I have been offered another job in a company in GCC (Gulf Cooperation Council). GCC has mainly three industries: 1) Petrochemical 2) Real-estate 3) Banking (Islamic & non-Islamic) and most of the companies included in these industries. Hence, part of my newly offered job would be studying various banks in GCC (sometime outside GCC) and recommending the manager to invest or not on a particular bank/banks (either Islamic or no-Islamic). It’s a lucrative offer and I know opportunities like this don’t knock our door very often. But, I am very much concerned that whether I will break the law of Allah by studying and recommending non-Islamic banks which is, as mentioned earlier, is a part of the job. I really need a help as soon as possible. 
May Allah guide us to the right path.

Comment: I certainly have no answer for you but I wish to enlighten you. Why not istikharah? It will move your heart to what's best for you according to the plans He made. But remember that recommending what is against Islam, apparently is not a good thing and will only bring you the unwanted sins, subhanallah. Submit yourself to Him, He will open your heart to the best answer for He is the planner of the past and future. I wish you all the best in your decision, remember, this might also be a test of your patience and gratitude.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read that istikharah can only be performed in matters which are neither obligatory nor prohibited. If recommending banking stocks is against islam, can I perform  istikharah?

Comment: @Salaah You may always [ask a new question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as to when Salat Al Istikhara should be made.

Answer (score 1):

**Recommending someone to invest in a non-Islamic bank** seems to be a wrongdoing (Munkar). So based on the following Ayah, I don't think you're allowed to do so:

> الْمُنَافِقُونَ وَالْمُنَافِقَاتُ بَعْضُهُم مِّن بَعْضٍ ۚ **يَأْمُرُونَ
>   بِالْمُنكَرِ** وَيَنْهَوْنَ عَنِ الْمَعْرُوفِ وَيَقْبِضُونَ أَيْدِيَهُمْ
>   ۚ نَسُوا اللَّهَ فَنَسِيَهُمْ ۗ إِنَّ الْمُنَافِقِينَ هُمُ
>   الْفَاسِقُونَ
>
> The hypocrite men and hypocrite women are of one another. **They enjoin
>   what is wrong and forbid what is right** and close their hands. They
>   have forgotten Allah , so He has forgotten them [accordingly]. Indeed,
>   the hypocrites - it is they who are the defiantly disobedient.
>
> [[At-Tawbah: 67]](http://quran.com/9/67)

If you can stay in your job and just recommend the managers to invest in Islamic banks, then it's OK. Otherwise, if I were you I'd have given up my job.